# count using awk commands

Tags: linux, awk, count

I have fileA.txt and a few lines of it are shown below:

```
AA
BB
CC
DD  
EE
```

And i have fileB.txt, and it has text like shown below:

```
Group  col2   col3    col4
1    pp    4567    AA,BC,AB
1    qp    3428    AA
2    pp    3892    AA
3    ee    28399   AA
4    dd    3829    BB,CC
1    dd    27819   BB
5    ak    29938   CC
```

For every line in fileA.txt, it should count the number of times it is present in fileB.txt based on column1 in fileB.txt.

Sample output should look like:

```
AA    3
BB    2
CC    2
```

AA is present 4 times but it is present in the group "1" twice. If it is present more than once in the same group in column1,it should be counted only once and therefore in the above output AA count is 3.

Any help using awk or any other oneliners?

Comment: "Oneliners"? Is the goal terseness? Correctness? Performance?

Comment: ...the short form is that many, if not most, of the times I see folks using one-liners, they're doing so for bad reasons. Better to write code that's easy to read, understand and modify, even if it's a bit longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` one-liner that should work:

```
awk '
NR==FNR && !seen[$4,$1]++{count[$4]++;next}
($1 in count){print $1,count[$1]}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Explaination:

- `NR==FNR&&!seen[$4,$1]++` pattern is only true when Column 1 has not been captured at all. For all duplicate captures we dont increment the counter.
- `$1 in count` looks for first file column 1 presence in array. If it is present, we print along with counts.

**Output:**

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR && !seen[$4,$1]++{count[$4]++;next}($1 in count){print $1,count[$1]}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
AA 3
BB 2
CC 1
```

#### Update based on the modified question:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {
  n = split($4,tmp,/,/);
  for(x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
    if(!seen[$1,tmp[x]]++) {
      count[tmp[x]]++
      }
    }
  next
}
($1 in count) {
    print $1, count[$1]
}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

**Outputs:**

```
AA 3
BB 2
CC 2
```

Comment: could you look at the initial question. I have  modified the column4 in fileB.txt.

Comment: could u let me know about $1 corresponds to which file? since i have to adapt it to my original file column numbers. If im right, $1 in the if loop corresponds to fileB and $1 outside loop corresponds to fileA?

Comment: @user1779730 Yes, thats correct. For `NR==FNR` section `$1` corresponds to fileB and for `($1 in count)` section it corresponds to fileA

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash (4.0 or newer):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A items=()

# read in the list of items to track
while read -r; do items[$REPLY]=0; done <fileA.txt

# read fourth column from fileB and increment for each match
while read -r _ _ _ item _; do
  [[ ${items[$item]} ]] || continue    # skip unrecognized values
  items[$item]=$(( items[$item] + 1 )) # otherwise, increment
done <fileB.txt

# print output
for key in "${!items[@]}"; do          # iterate over keys
  value="${items[$key]}"               # look up values
  printf '%s\t%s\n' "$key" "$value"    # print them together
done
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple awk one-liner.

```
awk 'NR>FNR{if($0 in a)print$0,a[$0];next}!a[$4,$1]++{a[$4]++}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

Note the order of files.

Comment: If i understand correctly, $0 refers to the column in fileA.txt and $4,$1 refers to the columns in fileB.txt. Am i right?

Comment: could you look at the initial question. I have modified the column4 in fileB.txt.